# How do I send data to Firestore when app is killed?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, background

I have been working on a project where I need to get the location data of a user and send it to Firestore in the background(ie, when the app is killed)

Is this possible to do? If yes how? If not how do I try to implement something similar?

I am using flutter to build the app.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of [Cloud Firestore's offline data persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)? Does this help in your use case?

Comment: Hey @tzovourn! Thanks for your reply but Firestore offline data persistence is not what I am looking for. I want a way for my app to send location data to firestore every second even when the app itself is killed. (ie the net connectivity is not an issue here). Is there a way you could help me with this?

Comment: any solutions, I tested it when the app is killed it doesnt receive callbacks, only solution that comes to my mind is using fcm

Answer (score 0):

In Callback Function we just need to initialize Firebase then it will continue to work as expected

```
 Future<void> update(data) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Coll").add({
      "time": DateTime.now().toIso8601String()
    });
}
```

That`s all.